# How can I execute code with a list of arguments

Tags: python-3.x, arguments, execution

I want to run a process in the following way

`python3 code_to_execute.py arg-1`

But I want to run it for n arguments (arg-1,...,arg-n). I can run it this way

```py
python3 code_to_execute.py arg-2
python3 code_to_execute.py arg-3
.
.
.
python3 code_to_execute.py arg-n
```

But I'd like to know if it can be run with just one line. Otherwise maybe I can create a .sh file with all the executables and run just the .sh

Thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a linux/WSL terminal, then you could use 'xargs':

```
echo arg-1 arg-2 arg-3 | xargs -n 1 python3 code_to_execute.py
```